# Does adding AsNoTracking in Entity Framework impact a Count?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Does adding AsNotracking function to a count in Entity Framework 6 has an impact on a count? More specifically does it improve or decrease performance or will the count result get cached?

With AsNoTracking

```
myContext.Products.AsNoTracking().Count();
```

Without AsNoTracking

```
myContext.Products.Count();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since no entities are being generated with this query, there is nothing to track, therefore no difference in performance. The SQL generated from this would look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM [dbo].[Products]
```

which obviously returns a single row. If it was creating entities to be tracked, it would have to return every single entity in that table.